# Unable to iterate over an array in hash in Perl script

Tags: perl

Please help me resolve this issue

## pre_package_config.pm

```
use strict;
our %pre_pkg_configs;

$pre_pkg_configs{locDbList}=['default','default_test'];
```

## second.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Expect;
use strict;

our %pre_pkg_configs;

my  $pre_pkg_file = './pre_package_config.pm';

eval {require $pre_pkg_file};

foreach my $db ( $pre_pkg_configs{locDbList} ){
    print $db;
}
```

## Output:

ARRAY (0x10092ae88)

## Should have been:

default
default_test

Comment: When debugging, use the [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3A%3ADumper) module to print your debugging information. It will make things much easier for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$pre_pkg_configs{locDbList}` is a single (scalar) value. Iterating over it would simply give you that one value (which happens to be a reference to an array). If you want to iterate over the contents of that array, you need to dereference:

```
for my $db (@{ $pre_pkg_configs{locDbList} }) {
    print $db;
}
```

Note that this will output `defaultdefault_test`, not `default default_test`. The easiest way to get the latter would be:

```
print join(" ", @{ $pre_pkg_configs{locDbList} }), "\n";
```

To learn more about references, see [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).
(Also, you should `use warnings;` in every file in addition to `use strict;`.)

Comment: but I have set the `$pre_pkg_configs{locDbList}` an array in previous file ? e.g `$pre_pkg_configs{locDbList}=['default','default_test'];`

Comment: What I should do to make $pre_pkg_configs{locDbList} an array over which I can iterate ?

Comment: @sakhunzai No, that's a reference to an array, not an array. Hashes can't contain arrays, they can only contain scalars. See [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).